# How can I send a message always to the same broker between two different Kafka clusters in .NET

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, apache-kafka

I have a large amount data but I want to split them and if I send a messageA to clusterA, messageA always should go to the clusterA.

How can I achieve that? I want to send a message always to same kafka cluster

Comment: I'm afraid your question is not clear enough

Answer (score 0):

Kafka producers can only be configured to one cluster at a time, already, so there is nothing more to do than set `bootstrap servers` accordingly.